# Проблема с функцией exec() php

Tags: php, debian, exec

Пытаюсь выполнить такое

```
exec('cd /home/admin/web/www.site.ru/public_html/css/&&sass --watch main.scss:main.css --style compressed',$out);
```

страница долго виснет и выдает 500 ошибку. Если выполнить

```
exec('cd /home/admin/web/www.site.ru/public_html/css/&&ls',$out);
```

все хорошо, получаю список файлов.
Что я делаю не так?

Система Debian 8

Comment: Смотрите логи web-сервера. причины 500 ошибок там обычно написаны

Answer (score 2):

`exec('cd /home/admin/web/www.site.ru/public_html/css/&&sass --watch' )`

&&sass у вас выполняется. но: вы запускаете его не в фоне, php работает в один поток, sass запускается, php ждет, когда он прекратит работу, чтобы вернуть результат, sass запущен с `--watch`, выходить из цикла наблюдения он не собирается,  поэтому php ждет вечно, веб-серверу и браузеру все это надоедает, вы получаете ошибку.

Попробуйте запустить 
`cd /home/admin/web/www.site.ru/public_html/css/&&sass --watch main.scss:main.css --style compressed &`, насколько я помню, sass тогда улетит в фон, exec возвратится, и скрипт продолжит работу дальше.

Правда, если вы вставляете это в скрипт на стороне браузера, с каждым обновлением страницы у вас будет запускаться все больше и больше эзкемпляров sass (если он не следит за своими экземплярами, конечно - тут я не в курсе, следит он или нет). Правда, вам никто не мешает запустить sass в отдельном процессе просто через ssh, не вставляя вызов в php-скрипт

Т.е. у вас нет проблемы с функцией exec, а есть проблема с пониманием архитектурной связки php/веб-сервер/ос.

Когда вы делаете `ls` - вы просто запускаете команду, получаете вывод. Когда вы запускаете `sass --watch` - запускаете с бесконечным циклом.

P.S.  `&&` это конструкция, специфичная для шелла. Она выполнит команду, если предыдущая команда не вернула ошибку. Ставьте пробелы вокруг `&&` и других `>` операторов шелла, кроме `;`, Это просто хороший тон. Пробел не следует ставить перед `;`, но следует ставить после, это как точка в предложении.